# System.Drawing and System.Drawing.Imaging alternatives for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm trying to use some C# snippets which doesn't work in Windows Phone, because of those namespaces.
Are there any alternatives to `System.Drawing` and `System.Drawing.Imaging` for windows phone?

I need alternatives to `PixelFormat`, `Bitmap`, `ColorPalette`, `ImageLockMode`, `LockBit` and so on.

---

an example:

```
    BitmapData bmpDat = bmp.LockBits(
        new Rectangle(
        0,0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height),
        ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never tried it, but I believe should be a good library.

http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

Good luck.