# How to Create an Image from Rectangle

Tags: windows-phone-8

I need the ability to be able to create an image of size 400x400 on the fly in a Windows Phone app, which will have a color of ARGB values that a user selects from a color picker. For instance, the user will click on a HyperlinkButton to take them to a ColorPickerPage and then will select a color, and I will retrieve that value and create the image from it, and display this image back on the MainPage. How might something like this be accomplished one I have retrieved the ARGB value from the user? I have not had luck finding any resources on this particular issue.

EDIT**

I came across http://www.geekchamp.com/forums/windows-phone-development/how-to-correctly-save-uicontrol-with-opacity-to-writeablebitmap which creates a rectangle on the screen and then saves to WriteableBitmap, but how might I skip that step and just save the Rectangle to WriteableBitmap? Note, I only have a single rectangle that I Fill with a custom Color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save any UI element as an image using the code below. Here `rect` is the name of the rectangle in your XAML. If the rectangle isn't present in the UI then simply create one using C#. I have added the code to create a rectangle using C# and commented it.

```
public void saveimage(int height, int width, String filename)
    {
        //Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        //rect.Height = 40;
        //rect.Width = 40;
        //rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Cyan); 
        var bmp = new WriteableBitmap(width, height);
        bmp.Render(rect, null);
        bmp.Invalidate();
        var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        if (!isf.FileExists(filename))
        {
            using (var stream = isf.OpenFile(filename, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                bmp.SaveJpeg(stream, width, height, 0, 100);
                stream.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this take into account the Alpha channel of an item in the View. It is possible in some situations that the alpha channel of the Rectangle's color be less than 255. It does not seem that the image is transparent once saving using the above method.

Comment: Could you demonstrate how to save a rectangle as an image if the rectangle is not on the UI?

Comment: I have added the code to do so and commented it. You simply need to create a rectangle using C# and then use it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the `Drawing` Class.

here's the [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawing(v=vs.110).aspx) from msdn.

These are some samples: [System.Drawing and System.Drawing.Imaging alternatives for Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486295/)

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Multi-Touch-Drawing-744a0b48

Hope it helps!